# How I can convert this Generic Class to a Parcelable?

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I want to convert this generic class to a parcelable object, but I don't have very clear the concepts of the issue.

Class:

```
public class Type<T> implements Parcelable {

    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }

    public T get() { return t; }

}
```

This is what I've tried,. but I know that this is not correct, or maybe this is not complete.

```
public class Type<T> implements Parcelable {

    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    protected Type(Parcel in) {
    }

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }

    public T get() { return t; }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    }

    public static final Creator< Type > CREATOR = new Creator< Type >() {
        @Override
        public Type createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Type(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Type[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Type[size];
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: I've posted it.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar approach as vikas kumar but guarantte that you can pass only Parcelable as T parameter so you avoid exception.

```
public class Type<T extends Parcelable> implements Parcelable {
    private T t;

    protected Type(Parcel in) {
        t = (T) in.readValue(t.getClass().getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Creator<Type> CREATOR = new Creator<Type>() {
        @Override
        public Type createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Type(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Type[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Type[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your generic data type may cause runtime error

so make sure you implements Parcelable and also the class you are passing should implement Parcelable otherwise it will cause runtime error.

```
     public class Type<T extends Parcelable> implements Parcelable {

    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }

    public T get() { return t; }


    protected Type(Parcel in) {
        final String className = in.readString();
        try {
            t = in.readParcelable(Class.forName(className).getClassLoader());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("readParcelable", className, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(t);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Type> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Type>() {
        @Override
        public Type createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Type(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Type[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Type[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using a Andorid Parcelable Generator but with private T t, there were errors.

Comment: t = (T) in.readValue(T.class.getClassLoader()); is warning me with an error. I don't know how to fix it :D

Comment: Works. How I can use it?

Comment: just create Type<YourClass> obj  = new Type<YourClass>();

Comment: But I need to reference this on a method like: public void method_x(Type<T> typeObject{}) But I get an error saying that T is not defined.